# How do I detect when the main thread has finished execution

Tags: c#, multithreading, logging

I have a logger which runs on it's own thread to prevent slowing down the main thread. Making it single-threaded would be easier, but I have a lot of slow code (writing to multiple files, getting info from stacktraces) and so on. The order of execution is:

**Main thread**

```
Logger.Log("foo"); //Creates stack trace for me
//Message and stack trace get added to queue
```

**Logger thread (in while loop)**

```
//Sees queued message
//Formats it (slow)
//Writes it to (one or more) streams and the console (*very* slow)
```

My problem is that if I make the logger thread a foreground thread, it prevents the app from closing once `Main` finishes, but if I make it background, it often gets cut off and doesn't manage to write most of the messages that were logged recently. Is there any way to make a function that will 'flush' the queue run just before the app quits, while keeping the thread background? (I can't always assume that people using my library will call a function before the app quits, and in certain cases (*cough* Unity *cough*) they really don't have much control)

Comment: You might consider using a tried-and-true logging library. I know Serilog has a Flush() method for just that purpose. Logging is not trivial, don't write it unless you have a compelling reason.

Comment: My main reason for writing my own is because I need to be able to customize it easily, such as writing to several files, changing the message format, etc).

Comment: OK, so Serilog, or NLog, or Log4Net. You can write to files, to App Insights, to an http endpoint, console, email, etc. etc. with formatting. https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Provided-Sinks

Comment: Awesome! I didn't realise that they were so customisable. I guess I'll use Serilog then. Thanks.

Comment: Back to the question: "I would use something like an `IDisposable` using to cleanup the Logger thread and wait until it is finished. _(like setting an WaitEvent)_"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need some kind of synchronization between your threads.  Instead of using your own Threads, consider using Tasks, these still run as Threads.  From inside the main thread  you can wait for the other tasks to finish or even signal them using a CancellationTokens.

When your "other logger thread" gets the Cancellation it can flush and exit it's log.

Here's a demo using Serilog with the Console Sink, you would probably want to use two different ILogger instances.

```
    static async Task OtherLoggerAsync(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        await Task.Yield();

        // This method is now running on it's own thread
        while (true)
        {
            Log.Information("Other logger logged on thread");
            await Task.Delay(750); // Mimic some work

            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Log.Logger.Information("OtherLoggerAsync() exiting");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .CreateLogger();

        using (CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            // Create the cancellation token
            var ct = cts.Token;

            // Start the other logger with the cancellation token
            var t = OtherLoggerAsync(ct);

            // Still in the main thread
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Log.Logger.Information("Main thread logged");
                await Task.Delay(1000); // Mimic some work
            }

            // Main thread has finished.  We want to stop the OtherLogger Thread
            // if it has finsihed or not.

            // signal the cancellation
            cts.Cancel();

            // wait for it to finish
            Task.WaitAll(t);

            Log.Logger.Information("Main thread exiting");
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }
```

Comment: *This method is now running on it's own thread* <== Most probably it's running on various thread-pool threads, not on a dedicated thread.